# The correct way to import and use the datetime python library

Tags: python, datetime

Why can't I just do datetime.now()?  Python doesn't like this??  Whats the correct why to import and use the datetime library in python...?

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print "Time: %d:%02d - Date: %d/%d/%d <br>" %(now.hour, now.minute, now.month, now.day, now.year)
```

Comment: btw you should use strftime for formatting. `http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are importing the datetime module (which contains classes for manipulating dates and times as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)) not the datetime object. In such classes and objects inside the datetime module exists an object named [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) (yes, the same name as the module where it lives), so to use the datetime object the way you want you need to import it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
#       ^               ^
#       |               |
#    module      class inside module

# Now you can use
now = datetime.now()
```

Comment: This works... however, eclipse syntax checker doesn't like that "import datetime" after the from datatime for some reason however, the interpreter thinks its okay.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) *module* contains a number of *classes*, including the class [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects). If you don't care about the other functions in the module, you can write:

```
from datetime import datetime as datetime_class
datetime_class.now()
```

However, I strongly suggest simply writing `datetime.datetime.now()`.